# Is it possible to use Alembic in BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, alembic, looping

I am thinking to make some cool looping animation, bake it into Alembic and have it working as BGE demoscene animation (looping). But is it possible to use Alembic animation in BGE?

Comment: The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/pipeline/alembic.html) mention how to export, in the [API Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=Alembic&check_keywords=yes&area=default) there's some references to BPY and none of BGE and mister Google unusefull links. So i will say probably not and i've been try it before :p

Comment: Please see my UPBGE looping animation answer here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251535/updating-frame-counter-in-bge-upbge-so-that-geometry-nodes-modifiers-can-do-cycl

Answer (score 0):

Using the Logic Blocks, add an Always Active Python script.

The python script content:

```
import bge # the module to interact with the Blender Game Engine
import bpy
import time
controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner
frame = time.monotonic()
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_set(int(frame*20.0)%300)
```

The attached file has an imported alembic animation of falling drops from:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/water-drops-animation-as-alembic-cache-16cb210c522041ceb196670b17bb3182

You can also follow my answer here:
[Updating frame counter in BGE/UPBGE so that Geometry Nodes modifiers can do cyclic animation in the game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251535/updating-frame-counter-in-bge-upbge-so-that-geometry-nodes-modifiers-can-do-cycl)

With the only difference being the conversion to int of the frame value.

[image]