# Updating frame counter in BGE/UPBGE so that Geometry Nodes modifiers can do cyclic animation in the game engine

Tags: python, game-engine, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to get the frame property increment similar to the way the timeline does so that animations in Geometry nodes will work in BGE?
The increment could be either infinite or cyclic through a range of frame numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after digging inside the python time,bpy and bge I found a way to simulate the timing advance of the #frame variable.

Using the following python script inside the BGE Logic Block:

```
import bge # the module to interact with the Blender Game Engine
import bpy
import time
controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner
frame = time.monotonic()
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_set(int((frame*20)%500))
```

I used the python monotonic time counter multiplied by 20 to get somewhere close to the way that the timeline advances. I also used mod 500 which is my desired frame range.

[image: Adding the python script for #frame advance]

[image]

Comment: Beware, this will only work inside Blender and not in the BGE Standalone Player.
I hope someone can come-up with a better solution that works in the player.